# Slim $app->render issues for a JSON API

Tags: php, json, api, slim

This is a fairly simple Slim $app->render question, but I'm using an SQL query to return the total number of columns in a table via `$result`, and the data stored in it looks like this: `[{"total":"12345"}]`

I want to push that out to a JSON API like so:

```
$app->get('/api/total/', function() use ($app) {
  $query = "select count(*) AS total FROM sometable";
  $data = $app->db->query($query);
  $result = $data->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
  $app->render(
    200, json_encode(array(
      'total' => $result['total']
    ))
  );
});
```

How do I make Slim's $app->render produce `{total:12345}` ?

Doing `'total' => $result['total']` throws errors such as:

> NOTICE: Undefined index: total

Comment: You need to convert the array to json first, try `json_encode()`

Comment: Could you provide more detail?

Comment: At the point you need to return the value. `$app->render(200, json_encode(array(
    'total' => $result['total']
)));`

Comment: What error is thrown exactly?

Comment: @mgansler updating my main post, sec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because fetchAll returns array of results. You could use `fetch()` instead. It would be also nice to check if fetch does not fail. However in this particular case if sometable exists it should not. Also you use fetch_obj and you try to access it as an array which is wrong. Either use `FETCH_ASSOC` or use `FETCH_OBJ` with proper object access.

```
$app->get('/api/total/', function() use ($app) {
  $query = "select count(*) AS total FROM sometable";
  $data = $app->db->query($query);
  $result = $data->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
  if($result !== false) {
    $app->render(
     200, json_encode(array(
      'total' => $result->total
      ))
   );
  } else {
     $app->render(
     404, json_encode(array(
      'error' => 'Not Found'
      ))
   );
  }
 });
```

Also remember it is good to set content type

```
$app->response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

If you need to know how fetching works check: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Comment: This results in a fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: because it is fetch_obj so u need use fetch as array or use `$result->total` I've updated my answer

Comment: Thank you, you're immensely helpful.